# delete array in C++ causing program crash

Tags: c++, pointers, opengl, graphics, delete-operator

I am following along with a youtube tutorial concerning opengl (a graphics programming library). I've created classes called vertex, ShapeData and ShapeGenerator. The overall idea is I'm creating code which will hold data for any type of shape I decide to come up with and want to display to the screen. The problem is my program seems to crash once the first "delete[]" is hit within ShapeData.h in the cleanup() function. Here is the relevant code:

Vertex.h

```
#pragma once
#include "GLM/glm.hpp"

class Vertex
{
public:
    Vertex();
    Vertex(glm::vec3 thePosition, glm::vec3 theColor);
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 color;
};
```

Vertex.cpp

```
#include "Vertex.h"

Vertex::Vertex()
{}

Vertex::Vertex(glm::vec3 thePosition, glm::vec3 theColor) :
    position(thePosition),
    color(theColor)
{
}
```

ShapeData.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Vertex.h"
#include "GL/glew.h"

struct ShapeData
{
    ShapeData() :
        verticies(0), numberOfVerts(0),
        indicies(0), numberOfIndicies(0)
    {}
    Vertex* verticies;
    GLuint numberOfVerts;
    GLushort* indicies;
    GLuint numberOfIndicies;
    GLsizeiptr VertexBufferSize() const
    {
        return numberOfVerts * sizeof(Vertex);
    }
    GLsizeiptr IndexBufferSize() const
    {
        return numberOfIndicies * sizeof(GLushort);
    }
    void CleanUp()
    {
        delete[] verticies;
        delete[] indicies;
        verticies = 0;
        indicies = 0;
        numberOfIndicies = 0;
        numberOfVerts = 0;
    }
};
```

ShapeGenerator.cpp

```
#include "ShapeGenerator.h"


ShapeData ShapeGenerator::MakeTriangle()
{
    Vertex triangle[] = {
        Vertex(glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)),
        Vertex(glm::vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)),
        Vertex(glm::vec3(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f))
    };
    ShapeData shapeData;

    shapeData.numberOfVerts = sizeof(triangle) / sizeof(*triangle);
    shapeData.verticies = new Vertex[shapeData.numberOfVerts];
    memcpy(shapeData.verticies, triangle, sizeof(triangle));
    shapeData.verticies = triangle;

    GLushort indicies[] = { 0,1,2 };
    shapeData.numberOfIndicies = sizeof(indicies) / sizeof(*indicies);
    shapeData.indicies = new GLushort[shapeData.numberOfIndicies];
    memcpy(shapeData.indicies, indicies, sizeof(indicies));

    return shapeData;
}
```

I'm trying to create a triangle and everything works fine without running the cleanup() function within main. Here is the portion where I'm calling Cleanup() in main:

main.cpp

```
ShapeData triangle = ShapeGenerator::MakeTriangle();

    GLuint bufferID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &bufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangle.VertexBufferSize(), triangle.verticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 3));

    GLuint indexBufferID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangle.IndexBufferSize(),triangle.indicies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    triangle.CleanUp();
```

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I see raw pointers and `memcpy` instead of vectors and assignments.

Comment: What is `concerning opengl (a graphics programming library)` I never heard of it -_-

Comment: It's spelt "vertices".

Comment: @KostasRim: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit dude I was kidding! In his question, he was pointing out that openGL is a graphics library. How would you answer a question about openGL if you don't know what openGL is(except if it is a language problem) ? I just found it funny that's all. P.S it was nice of you `baby spooning` me by providing a wikipedia link.

Comment: @KostasRim: Hilarious. P.S. the word you are looking for is "spoon-feeding".

Comment: Ha, well I know not everyone is familiar with opengl and I didn't feel this question could only be answered by those familiar with opengl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are replacing the new[]'d pointer here.  This causes a crash because triangle is not new[]'d.

```
shapeData.verticies = new Vertex[shapeData.numberOfVerts];
memcpy(shapeData.verticies, triangle, sizeof(triangle));
shapeData.verticies = triangle;
```